# What should I use as return type of method IEnumerable, IList, Collection or what

Tags: c#, .net, collections, ienumerable, ilist

I am making a library which is going to be used widely by different applications. You can say that it is sort of a public library or SDK.

Currently I am working on a function which takes a list of Points performs some calculation on these points and then return list of updated points. So my question here is what should I use as return type and in my parameters. `IList`, `IEnumerable` or `Collection`.

So here it the function. I am unaware what user will do with the output. How user uses it, is on him. So what should be best option to use here.

```
public static IEnumerable<Point2D> PeformSomeCalculation(IEnumerable<Point2D> points)
{
    // Do something,
    return updatedPoints;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `IList<T>` interface inherits from `ICollection<T>`, `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerable`.

So if you return an `IList<T>`, clients that want an `ICollection<T>`, an `IEnumerable<T>` or just an `IEnumerable` will all be happy.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the points collection to be manipulated?

If so use [`ICollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx) or an `IList` as these expose `Add`, `Clear` and `Remove` methods.

If you need the list to be indexed then you should choose [`IList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx) - this interface inherits from `ICollection` and `IEnumerable` so this may be what you are after.

If you do not require the collection to be modified or indexed then use [`IEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

As a parameter you should use the most specific required type. It's mean if you need in function only functionality of IEnumarable you should use IEnumarable, not ICollection or IList.

And as a return type you should use the most general type, but you should be aware for ICollection and IList type. If you use this in Linq to SQL - this function has method contains but Linq cannot translate this function in this type to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Generally I would try not to build assumptions into what the user will do, unless I am trying to enforce a rule such as this collection is read only, so I would use the most general type. Also you may consider implementing an **[iterator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dscyy5s0.aspx)**, as you are accepting a list and returning an updated list.

Making use of the **yield return** statement may be convenient for your clients allowing them ForEach functionality. Simple to implement.